# How to setting a model with table don't have any primary key column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-standard, entity-framework-core

On setting `DbContext`, we have

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(app =>
{
    app.ToTable("Person");
});
```

The EFCore throws an exception:

> The entity type "Person" requires a primary key to be defined

But our `Person` table doesn't have any primary key column.

How to avoid this ?

Comment: As part of database standardisation, you should introduce a primary key column. Even if that means a simple `AUTO_INCREMENT` int value. You might never use the primary key, but its extremely useful for it to be there.

Comment: @Will I Understand, but in this case, change the table structure is not prefer because we are in migration mode

Comment: All EF versions (including the latest Core) does not support entities w/o PK. I don't think it wwill be changed, so you have to map some column(s) as PK.

Comment: I would recommend creating a new target table with a middleman algorithm to take your old data manually and insert it into the table, creating incrementing primary keys as you go along. Either that, or selecting an existing field as a primary key, if possible.

Comment: **Every** properly designed relational database table **must have** a primary key. This has always been true, and is being required more and more, with Entity Framework and Azure SQL. So just get used to having a PK - it doesn't **hurt** - quite the contrary! Just define a PK for each table and you're done

Comment: @marc_s Some migrate situation, the database permission is read-only, so we cannot change any table schema.

Comment: If it *doesn't have* a primary key, then EF **cannot** use it - period.

Answer (score 4):

EF Core doesn't support tables without primary keys (aka heaps). The reason is simple: it needs to be able to manipulate individual records, something that cannot be safely achieved without a primary key.
As a resolution, you can add a dummy column/primary key of type int/identity or guid/uniqueidentifier, and just ignore it.

Comment: In case read-only database, change table structure is not acceptable

Comment: True, but the question didn't mention anything about a read-only database.